# Dynamically loading property value from active list of profiles and set the value in configuration XML file

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring bath application which contains a batch configuration. I want to dynamically load profile based upon the environemnt variable parameter of active profile list.once i get the value, I have to set the variable in the batch configuration xml file. Its working fine while active profile value is single, its working fine if I give like

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application-${spring.active.profile}.properties" />
```

But i have a list of active profiles
eg: -Dspring.active.profile=dev,localproperties,mycerts. I want to take first value of active profile and load properties file and load application-dev.properties.
I tried the below way , but getting the entire entire string as profile value. how can i load the first value of active profile/.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <util:list>
                <value>classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties</value>
            </util:list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have a list of active profiles eg: -Dspring.active.profile=dev,localproperties,mycerts. I want to take first value of active profile

You can use a SpEL expression for that, something like:

```
<context:property-placeholder 
 location="classpath:application-#{environment.getActiveProfiles()[0]}.properties" />
```

Note that the property is named `spring.profiles.active` and not `spring.active.profile`.